# Increase height of converse-muc-embedded window

Tags: converse.js

Hi I am using conversejs client with converse-muc-embedded. I want to increase the height of the conversejs window that is populated. Is there a setting to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The height is specified in a Sass file.

You can change it there:
https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/blob/7c831e1166f9887a2739af0fd8038e16a8a7f7a8/sass/_muc_embedded.scss#L49

You then have to regenerate the CSS files by executing `make css` inside the repo.